# How run MongodDB dbStats command in java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I use following code to run mongodb dbStats command to get more details of databases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    MongoIterable<String> databases = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames();
    for (String dbName : databases) {
        System.out.println("- Database: " + dbName);
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);
        Document result = db.runCommand(new Document("dbStats", "1"));
        // read required database details
    }
    mongoClient.close();
}
```

That's based on MogoDB documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/), it should work correctly, but it throws exception:

> Command failed with error 73 (InvalidNamespace): 'Invalid db name: dbname.1' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is {....}

Comment: The value of `dbStats` in the document is numeric. Change `db.runCommand(new Document("dbStats", "1"))` to `db.runCommand(new Document("dbStats", 1))` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, it works, sorry for my negligent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [ernest_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5761558/ernest-k), it was careless,So this works:

```
db.runCommand(new Document("dbStats", 1))
```